# Akka: Immediately return 400 Bad Request on Case Class Validation Failure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

According to the docs on case class validation for parameter extraction ( the last section of the docs found here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html), if the validation fails, a ValidationRejection is returned and the request is sent further down to the next route.

What I would like it to do is instead immediately return a 400 Bad Request telling the user that they've sent invalid query parameter values. If the request goes on to the next route, this information will all be lost. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you give some sample code? This sounds similar to your previous question so can you show how it is different?